# combining resultset in a single select statement on same table mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `bills` having columns like `bill_id, company_id,transaction_id`.
I run two queries :

```
"Select bill_id from bills where cmp_id = 1 ";
"Select bill_id from bills where cmp_id = 2";
```

Both queries return expected results separately.
I require to output both columns of the two queries in a single select query.
I tried using UNION/UNION ALL but i get repeated results or only a single column result

```
(select bill_id from bills where cmp_id =1 ) as cmp1Bills
union
(select bill_id from bills where cmp_id =2)as cmp2Bills order by bill_id;
```

Desired output:

```
cmp1Bills    cmp2Bills
1              10
2              11
3              12
```

Comment: Please include sample data which explains what you want here.

Comment: Are you only ever looking at two different companies?

Comment: not necessarily..but its just an example

Answer (score 3):

Use IN to include a group of values that can match the column for a row to be included

```
Select bill_id 
from bills 
where cmp_id IN (1, 2)
order by bill_id
```

Comment: Use `SELECT DISTINCT` if the OP wants to remove duplicates.

Comment: It would be nice to provide additional information to OP as to WHY this is a correct answer.

Comment: thanks but this also returns the results in a single column..i needed it to be in separate columns for each company as if running the queries separately.

Comment: @pranay Your comment above makes no sense.  Please add data to your question.

Comment: @pranay if you start with "select bill_id from..." you'll obtain a single column. Maybe the solution is to hold cmp_id too: use the query of the answer but beginning with "select bill_id, cmd_id from..."

Comment: Now I read your edit; you can try to get a result like the one you expect by working with full join (if it doesn't work the command you have to do the union of a left and a right join). But...what's the meaning of everyrow of your output? Is there a link between bills 1 and 10?

Comment: the result means each billids associated with every each company...No,there is no relation between either billids.They are infact the primary key